# cloning two object in one

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to cloning two object in one ? I tried Object.assign() but doesn't worked.

I have this : `this.props.firstLetter[i]` the return of that on my console is : [image: firstLetter]

This two objects I would like to create one big object of these two.

With `Object.assign()`, I tried this : `Object.assign(this.props.firstLetter[i])`, but the result of them is only one entry, the last only.

You have solution ?

Please.

**EDIT 17/12/2017 :**

Create array, and push those two object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: No, because if you see in my screenshot the key for this two object are the same and if I use Object.assign() he send me back only one object of in my case the second object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.assign will effectively merge two objects, giving priority to the second one.

"cloning two objects into one" means overriding one objet with another, which yields you 1 object as result.

If your goal is to have two objects into one you have to assign different *keys*:

```
let group = {
  item1: obj1,
  item2: obj2 
}
```

If your goal (more likely) is to have a collection of same-type objects, group them into an array:

```
let groups = [
  obj1,
  obj2
]
```